# Confused about Putty colors - Centos 7

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty

So I am using nginx as my server if that helps at all. I also use Putty as my connection manager as well.

So while setting up domains here and there under nginx, there seems to be a difference in colors for some of the domains. I am really unsure why. Like if it is a concern at all.

[image]

I just setup a domain and it appears red as shown: http://puu.sh/m4scc/1baa60c2e9.png

I've hidden domain names for privacy reasons. The tutorial I used to setup nginx on my server is: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7

Information such as serverblock info is not what I use on there if that was a question of the viewers.

You may also see in my image two domains don't have a directory on the right side. I believe during the setup of those 2, I did not create a symbolic link between them. But no performance/uptime issues with them.

EDIT:

I have also read this that my friend linked me, but they don't seem to correlate with what I am facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942479/what-do-each-of-puttys-text-colours-represent

EDIT 2:

Ok so I solved my problem in a way. More of getting it to be blue. It looks like there was a small typo in the symbolic link, so it was read because it must of been invalid. Typed it all out again and it appears blue. Staff can close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red link is link to non-existing file and means that it is invalid. It is because of missing slash `/` in the beginning.

For more, the other colors are dependent on [different access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942479/what-do-each-of-puttys-text-colours-represent), as you have already found out.